# python указать путь к файлу .so

Tags: python, linux, cython

Пытаюсь установить библиотеку [PyCLP](https://github.com/pellico/pyclp/tree/master/pyclp) ([описание](https://pythonhosted.org/PyCLP/)) на ubuntu

Успешно установил

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

Данная библиотека работает с [eclipseCLP](http://eclipseclp.org/) для [версии 6.1](http://eclipseclp.org/Distribution/Builds/6.1_229/)

eclipseCLP v6.1 тоже установлен, работает

Пытаюсь просто воспользоваться PyCLP:

```
from pyclp import *
```

Получаю ошибку импорта:

> file "/usr/bin/..."
>
> from pyclp.pyclp import *
>
> ImportError: libeclipse.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Где сама библиотека `libeclipse.so` знаю (/home/ECLIPSEDIR/lib/x86_64_linux)

Пробовал указать ее в PATH

```
PATH=$PATH:/home/ECLIPSEDIR/lib/x86_64_linux
```

не помогло

В [документации](http://eclipseclp.org/doc/embedding/embroot004.html#sec7) самого eclipseclp есть инструкция, как указать libeclipse.so для инклюда в .с файлы (gcc):

```
gcc -I$ECLIPSEDIR/include/$ARCH eg_c_basic.c -L$ECLIPSEDIR/lib/$ARCH -leclipse
```

Вот нужно примерно такое, только для python

Comment: Я думаю можно ее просто скопировать в проект.
Правда у нее может оказаться много зависимостей...

Comment: Вот потому и надо следовать дистрибутивным пакетам.
@Victor, для этого существует команда `ldd`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пропишите в Ваш *profile* или *.bashrc* (в зависимости от дистрибутива) установку значения переменной LD_LIBRARY_PATH:

> LD_LIBRARY_PATH is the search path environment variable for the linux
> shared library
>
> In Linux, the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH is a colon-separated (:) set of directories where libraries are searched
> for first before the standard set of directories.

Проще говоря, если Вы напишите в *profile* нечто вроде

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="<Путь к вашей so-шке>:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

то система будет начинать поиск so-шек с каталога, который вы ей подсунули.